# JS not sure why my load event wouldn't be firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, jquery-events

I have a blur up effect happening for image, and currently the blur animation starts when the DOM is loaded.

Only problem is I have some scripts loading from external resources, Google API etc.
Sometimes these scripts take a long time to load, so the jQuery document ready function takes a long time to fire.
As my blur up animation waits for the DOM to be ready, the images are blurry on the screen for much longer than I would like.

I thought well rather than wait for the DOM to load, maybe I could just wait until the footer is rendered and use the load event to trigger the blur up effect.

Here is the blur up SVG:

```
<svg width="0px" height="0px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <filter id="better-blurBrand-@counter" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1">
   <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="25" result="blurred">
      <animate id="animBrand-@counter" attributeType="XML" attributeName="stdDeviation" from="25" to="0" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" dur="0.35s"></animate>
   </feGaussianBlur>
   <feMorphology in="blurred" operator="dilate" radius="25" result="expanded"></feMorphology>
   <feMerge>
      <feMergeNode in="expanded"></feMergeNode>
      <feMergeNode in="blurred"></feMergeNode>
   </feMerge>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="image-wrapper clone" style="background-image: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,@brand.PictureModel.base64Img'); background-size: cover; background-position: bottom; filter: url(#better-blurBrand-@counter);"></div>
<div class="image-wrapper orig" style="background-image: url('@brand.PictureModel.ImageUrl'); background-size: cover; background-position: bottom; filter: url(#better-blurBrand-@counter);"></div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
@{ 
   string animBrand = string.Format("#animBrand-{0}", counter);// This is used to blur up each image and is C#
 }
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#responsive-footer").load(function () {
        if (jQuery('@animBrand')[0].beginElement) {
            jQuery('@animBrand')[0].beginElement();
        }
    });
</script>
```

If I use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     //animate code
}); it works fine
```

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4eu8ray/10/) of what I want to happen.

Anyone know why my load event is not firing. From what I read up on the [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) website it should work.

> UPDATE: I just realized the `<div id="responsive-footer">` element was
>   hidden by javascript, so it was not there in the DOM. I thought this
>   might be why but when I changed it to the actual footer element `<div
>   class="footer">` it still not work.

Cheers

Comment: Div elements don't have a load event. But even if they did, the [`.load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) doesn't bind an event handler (the [old](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event binding method has been removed from the latest jQuery, though you can use `.on("load")` instead for elements that support that event). Have you tried just calling your `.beginElement()` thing directly in a script element placed after the element(s) it manipulates? (With no event wrapper function.)

Comment: I thought about it but the blur up doesn't work in internet explorer. So i use this `if (!jQuery('#animBrand-0')[0].beginElement) {
                jQuery(".image-wrapper.orig").css({ "filter": "blur(25px)" });
            }` to make the blur up work in ie. The scripts taking a long time to load messes it all up. is there a way to use dom ready without relying on the scripts to be fully loaded